# Can i dynamically set rowspan in tablelayout or gridview?

Tags: android

I have a TableLayout and I want to add tablerows dynamically; but I need to set different rowspans.

I have no idea how do this and I've not been able to find a solution. Is there any way I can do this? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: for adding row at particular position you have addRow(index,view) with index in table layout

Comment: for the column span use TableRow.LayoutParams params = (TableRow.LayoutParams)editText.getLayoutParams();
params.span = toSpan;
editText.setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: thanks, but this did not work.. i have this http://imageshack.us/a/img812/9189/img1qz.png and i want this http://imageshack.us/a/img96/1016/img2tt.png